# Guzzle how to handle RequestException when host is offline

Tags: php, exception, guzzle

I am using Guzzle inside the laravel framework but when the host is offline I get a exception instead of a statuscode which you can get with `getStatusCode()`. I have now made a try catch around the request, but outside this method I have a method which checks on the statuscode. My question is how can I return in the catch the correct response so I could call outside this method `getStatusCode()`.

My code to make the request looks like this:

```
public function makeRequest($method, $requestUrl, $queryParams = [])
    {
        try{
            $client = new Client(['http_errors' => false]);
            return $client->request($method, $requestUrl, [
                'query' => $queryParams
            ]);
        }catch(RequestException $exception){
            LOG::info($exception->getMessage());
            return $exception->getResponse();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to catch other exception too like `ConnectException`,ClientException, ServerException

Comment: @AbuSayem RequestException seems to handle also ConnectException but will look in those other 2

Comment: in the latest edition, it is separated from RequestException https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/commit/6b77639250b6cae67c6645105f7123f1fc0b4018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea (always return `Response` object from the method) doesn't work by design. I mean that you see it already, there is no `Response` object is some cases (when a connection to the host cannot be established, for example, so HTTP flow doesn't even start in this case, that why you don't have any HTTP status code).

IMO the best way to make your code aware of the exception. Don't try to handle it inside your `makeRequest()`, just let it flow further, to the point where you actually can handle it.